# Perl evaluate condition based on passed values

Tags: perl, parameters, eval, conditional-statements

What is the best way to test an if condition in perl that parameter driven?

For eg: if condition 1 is if($str1 eq "abc") and condition 2 is if($str2 eq "xyz"), and at runtime the decision is made as to which condition needs to be checked, how would you do it?

```
$str1 = $ARGV[0];
$str2 = $ARGV[1];
$cond_value = $ARGV[2];

$cond1 = "$str1 eq \"abc\"";

$cond2 = "$str2 eq \"xyz\"";

if($cond_value == 1) {
  $return_val = eval($cond1);
}
else {
  $return_val = eval($cond2);
}
```

Doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example may be over-distilled. It worked when I tried it, although it's probably not doing what you intended (and it will fail with strict/warnings, as Justin says). The values of `$str1` and `$str2` are expanded when `$cond1` and `$cond2` are assigned, not inside `if ($cond_value)`. That can be fixed by escaping the dollar signs (`$cond1 = "\$str1 eq \"abc\"";`).

`eval` has a bunch of issues, though, including the trouble of figuring out the right escapes to use and possible security risks if you're working with untrusted data. You may want to consider using anonymous subroutines:

```
$cond1 = sub { $_[0] eq "abc" };
$cond2 = sub { $_[1] eq "xyz" };

$test = $cond_value ? $cond1 : $cond2;

$return_val = $test->($str1, $str2);
```

Comment: The problem I am facing though is that it might not always be an "eq" comparison. It could be <= or any such operator. Need the entire condition to be passed as a variable.

Comment: @Chris With either `eval` or anonymous subs, you can use an arbitrary condition. However, if the test condition can't be given a fixed interface (i.e., if the condition might need to look at any variable in your program), then `eval` is the way to go. The built-in [`sort` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) is a good example of tweaking an algorithm with a user-specified condition.

Answer (score 1):

Why so much work?

```
my $str_to_test  = $cond_value == 1 ? $str1 : $str2;
my $test_against = $cond_value == 1 ? "abc" : "xyz";

if($str_to_test eq $test_against) {
  # do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not that helpful from a perspective of how I would engineer "something *like* this". But this is how you could accomplish what you show

```
my $cond = $ARGV[2];
my $return_val = $ARGV[$cond - 1] eq [ qw<abc xyz> ]->[$cond - 1];
```

I just can't see the wider application from this toy program. Here's another variation:

```
my $return_val = $ARGV[$_] eq [ qw<abc xyz> ]->[$_] for $ARGV[2] != 1 || 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you're trying achieve this is quite odd, it might be easier to explain what you are trying to do to find a less unusual approach.

At any rate, not knowing what kind of things you are putting in $str1 and $str2 I'd guess that the problem is that the eval doesn't quite do what you expect. Think about what the string evaluates to and you'll see the problem:

```
$str  = "abc";
$cond = "$str eq \"abc\"";
```

$cond becomes:

```
abc eq "abc"
```

Which if you have strict and warnings on (you should!) and you check the result of your eval in $@ (you should!) you would find:

```
Bareword "abc" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at .....
```